# OS development, issues with floating point division resulting NaN

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I apologize in advance if my question isn't formatted in the best way, I'm new to asking questions here.

I've been interested in learning about operating system development lately, and I have run into some strange issues regarding floating point division in C. Even something as simple as `4.0f / 2.0f` gives me a NaN result. I suspect this may have something to do with the compiler, however I don't know how to verify that, I would very much appreciate help in fixing this, as I've been at this for a few hours and have made little to no progress with google searches.
Github for the project, if you'd like to build it: https://github.com/AsherBearce/ToyOperatingSystem

The relevant parts of my project are as follows:

**kernel/kernelmain.c:**

```
#include "screen.h"

void main(){   
    enableCursor(1, 14);
    clearScreen();
    double a = 4.0f;
    double b = 2.0f;
    double c = a / b;
    double ans = 2.0f;
    //Division is the ONLY operation that isn't yielding the correct results, in fact c turns out to be NaN!
    if (c == 2.0f){ 
        char string[] = "Hardcoded values were correct\n\0";
        print(string);
    }

    char out[] = "End output\0";
    print(out);

    while (1){

    }
}
```

**boot/bootsector.asm**

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16
mov ax, HELLO_MSG ;Print a simple hello message :D
call _printString
xor ax, ax
;Here, we'll load the kernel into RAM
call LoadKernel
;Enter protected mode
call EnterProtMode

EnterProtMode:
    cli ;Disable interrupts
    lgdt [gdt_pointer] ;Load the GDT register with the start address of the GDT
    mov eax, cr0
    or al, 1 ;Set PE (protection enable) bit in CR0
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp 08h:Stage2 ;Jump to stage 2

LoadKernel:
    mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET ;Load the kernel offset into bx
    mov dh, 16 ;Load 16 sectors 
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE] ;The disk to read from
    call diskload ;Load the kernel
    ret

bits 32
KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x1000
BOOT_DRIVE: db 0

Stage2:
    mov ax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp
    ;Kernel entry here
    jmp KERNEL_OFFSET ;Call the kernel finally

%include 'boot/printUtils.asm'
%include 'boot/gdt.asm'
%include 'boot/diskload.asm'

HELLO_MSG: db "Booted successfully, loading kernel.", 0
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

**Makefile**

```
BOOTOUTPUT = boot.bin
OSOUTPUT = os.bin
SRCS = $(shell find . -name '*.c')
CINC = $(shell find . -name '*.h')
COBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRCS))
OBJDIR = build

#Final step in the build process
$(OSOUTPUT): kernel.bin $(BOOTOUTPUT)
    cat $(BOOTOUTPUT) kernel.bin > $(OSOUTPUT)

#Assemble the boot sector code
$(BOOTOUTPUT): boot/bootsector.asm
    nasm -f bin boot/bootsector.asm -o $(BOOTOUTPUT)

#Compile all the kernel C files
%.o:%.c $(CINC)
    gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -fno-pie -fno-stack-protector -nostdlib -c $< -o $@

#Assemble the IRQ code
irq.o: kernel/irq.asm
    nasm kernel/irq.asm -f elf32 -o irq.o

#Assemble the kernel entry code
kernelEntry.o: boot/kernelEntry.asm
    nasm boot/kernelEntry.asm -f elf32 -o kernelEntry.o

#Link all the .o files with the kernel entry
kernel.bin: kernelEntry.o irq.o $(COBJS)
    ld -melf_i386 -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary

run: 
    qemu-system-x86_64 -fda $(OSOUTPUT)

clean:
    rm -f *.bin *.o $(COBJS)
```

Edit: I've decided to include the disassembly for kernelmain.c

```
kernelmain.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fb             endbr32 
   4:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
   8:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   b:   ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
   e:   55                      push   %ebp
   f:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  11:   51                      push   %ecx
  12:   83 ec 54                sub    $0x54,%esp
  15:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   16 <main+0x16>
  1a:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
  1d:   6a 0e                   push   $0xe
  1f:   6a 01                   push   $0x1
  21:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   22 <main+0x22>
  26:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
  29:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   2a <main+0x2a>
  2e:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   2f <main+0x2f>
  33:   dd 05 00 00 00 00       fldl   0x0
  39:   dd 5d f0                fstpl  -0x10(%ebp)
  3c:   dd 05 08 00 00 00       fldl   0x8
  42:   dd 5d e8                fstpl  -0x18(%ebp)
  45:   dd 45 f0                fldl   -0x10(%ebp)
  48:   dc 75 e8                fdivl  -0x18(%ebp)
  4b:   dd 5d e0                fstpl  -0x20(%ebp)
  4e:   dd 05 08 00 00 00       fldl   0x8
  54:   dd 5d d8                fstpl  -0x28(%ebp)
  57:   dd 45 e0                fldl   -0x20(%ebp)
  5a:   dd 05 08 00 00 00       fldl   0x8
  60:   df e9                   fucomip %st(1),%st
  62:   dd d8                   fstp   %st(0)
  64:   7a 56                   jp     bc <main+0xbc>
  66:   dd 45 e0                fldl   -0x20(%ebp)
  69:   dd 05 08 00 00 00       fldl   0x8
  6f:   df e9                   fucomip %st(1),%st
  71:   dd d8                   fstp   %st(0)
  73:   75 47                   jne    bc <main+0xbc>
  75:   c7 45 ac 48 61 72 64    movl   $0x64726148,-0x54(%ebp)
  7c:   c7 45 b0 63 6f 64 65    movl   $0x65646f63,-0x50(%ebp)
  83:   c7 45 b4 64 20 76 61    movl   $0x61762064,-0x4c(%ebp)
  8a:   c7 45 b8 6c 75 65 73    movl   $0x7365756c,-0x48(%ebp)
  91:   c7 45 bc 20 77 65 72    movl   $0x72657720,-0x44(%ebp)
  98:   c7 45 c0 65 20 63 6f    movl   $0x6f632065,-0x40(%ebp)
  9f:   c7 45 c4 72 72 65 63    movl   $0x63657272,-0x3c(%ebp)
  a6:   c7 45 c8 74 0a 00 00    movl   $0xa74,-0x38(%ebp)
  ad:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
  b0:   8d 45 ac                lea    -0x54(%ebp),%eax
  b3:   50                      push   %eax
  b4:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   b5 <main+0xb5>
  b9:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
  bc:   c7 45 cc 45 6e 64 20    movl   $0x20646e45,-0x34(%ebp)
  c3:   c7 45 d0 6f 75 74 70    movl   $0x7074756f,-0x30(%ebp)
  ca:   c7 45 d4 75 74 00 00    movl   $0x7475,-0x2c(%ebp)
  d1:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
  d4:   8d 45 cc                lea    -0x34(%ebp),%eax
  d7:   50                      push   %eax
  d8:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   d9 <main+0xd9>
  dd:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
  e0:   eb fe                   jmp    e0 <main+0xe0>
```

Comment: First of all, **never** use `f` for *double* literals! It means *float*.

Comment: Move the *calculation* into a function and *disassemble* it, and compare it with the disassembly of those calculations that seemingly work.

Comment: Also, having some experience with osdev, I suggest that after you've verified that you can write a bootloader, that you would *stop* using your bootloader and use Grub+multiboot instead. So much nicer :D

Comment: And finally my pet peeve: `*(VMEM + index) = fullchar;` should be written as `VMEM[index] = fullchar;` - easier to read.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I've tried disassembling kernel.bin, and the file is huge, it's impossible to find `main`.

Comment: well... one *more* reason to use Grub, you can use *ELF*. But you can disassemble the object file instead. Put 2 calculations into 2 functions, one working, one not working, objdump -d the object file having these functions...

Comment: More criticism: `char string[] = "Hardcoded values were correct\n\0";` this will make a string that ends wit *two* null characters, and will always make a *new* buffer for you (unless the optimizer realizes that this is silly and gives you a const one instead); you really want to just use `print("Hardcoded values were correct\n");`.

Comment: `double a = 4.0f;` doesn't make sense.  It's using a single-precision floating point constant to initialize a double-precision variable (and it's taking an extra character to do it).  Just do `double a = 4.0;`, i.e. get rid of the `f`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The only differences I found were that the compiled working code uses the xmm0 registers, whereas mine uses the st0 registers. HOWEVER in order to even get the code to compile, I had to compile to x64, but my OS is 32 bit.

Comment: @TomKarzes I have made that change, and I still get the same result.

Comment: First of all, only post the minimal amount of code which demonstrates the problem. The boot sector may be relevant, but the GDT and the disk code and the printing code definitely aren't! Since this is a CPU architecture problem it would also be good if you could show problematic *assembly* code rather than showing us the C code and hoping we can guess how it compiles to assembly.

Comment: @AbstractMath Right, that won't fix the problem, it's just bad form to do what you were doing (and in cases where the value cannot be exactly represented, the `f` will cause reduced precision).

Comment: I'd focus on `kernelmain.c`, since that seems to be where the problem lies.  Try looking at the assembly code.  Is the compiler generating code to do the divide, or is it being done at compile time?  Then see if you can eliminate everything but the divide - it's possible that some of the other code could be clobbering the stack.

Comment: @TomKarzes I have looked through the disassembly of kernelmain.c a few times now. Everything seems okay. Also, I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the stack. The only floating point operation that gives the wrong results is division.

Comment: @user253751 I have included the disassembly of kernelmain.c. Hopefully that helps, but most of the kernel is written in C. Hence why I showed the C code.

Comment: Okay, the fact still remains that you are supposed to show us the smallest possible code which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @user253751 I feel that since this is a pretty specific problem, it might be useful to have additional information about what I'm doing. Which, is also why I decided to link my entire github repo for this project.

Comment: No. A pretty specific problem has pretty specific code which demonstrates it. Which could be as simple as: a 32-bit boot loader (loaded by GRUB so you don't have to switch to 32-bit mode yourself) that divides two numbers and then puts 'X' or 'Y' on the screen depending on whether the answer was NaN.

Comment: @user253751 There, removed the irrelevant stuff.

Comment: I think the xmm0 could be reason, IIRC, the OS needs to enable support for some features explicitly

Comment: Does any floating-point calculation work? Does loading a floating-point number into the stack and storing it reproduce the original number or produce a NaN? Did you initialize the floating-point stack? Did you overflow the floating-point stack? How do you know you got a NaN; did you output it somewhere, see it using some debugging method, what?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, the other floating point operations appear to work fine. And no, I didn't realize I needed to initialize a floating point stack?

Comment: So addition works but division does not? Regarding initializing the floating-point stack, look into the `finit` instruction, which initializes the floating-point unit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Precisely. Addition works, division does not. Also, I found an OSdev forum post that describes FPU initialization. Is this right? https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21813

Comment: @EricPostpischil It doesn't appear that the resources on that website I linked were of much help, and adding the finit instruction in my bootloader didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around at various resources, I found this forum page on OSdev here:
forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21813 that described the process for first checking for an FPU, and then initializing it. Turns out that for whatever reason, my target platform does not have an FPU, which I'm guessing is the reason for the undefined behavior.